# I tried googling this. DoublyLinkedList question. Edited(2)

Tags: java

I am new to LinkedLists. We are working with DoublyLinkedLists and we have to do a method called addAfter. So I googled it and came up with nothing. The node class and variable initialation is given to us in a skeleton by him as well, so right away I am thinking, am I missing an initialation for newInfo and afterThis?. This is how he describes addAfter---

This method adds a new node containing the integer newInfo to the next of the node containing the integer afterThis. If there is no node containing the integer afterThis, insert the new node at the last. If there are multiple nodes containing the integer afterThis, insert the new node right next to the ﬁrst occurrence of afterThis in the list.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;



//import DoublyLinkedList.Node;



public class DoublyLinkedList {
    public static class Node {
        private int element;
        private Node prev, next;


        public Node(int e, Node p, Node n) {
            element = e;
            prev = p;
            next = n;
        }

        public  int getElement() {
            return element;
        }

        public Node getPrev() {
            return prev;
        }

        public Node getNext(){
            return next;
        }

        public void setPrev(Node p) {
            prev = p;
        }

        public void setNext(Node n) {
            next = n;
        }


    }
/***************************************************************************************************************************/   
    public DoublyLinkedList(String fileName) throws IOException {

        FileReader input = new FileReader(fileName); // this is where it reads the filenames HW4-A and myAnotherInput
        BufferedReader myReader = new BufferedReader(input);
        String line = "";

        while ((line = myReader.readLine()) != null) {
            int nextNumber = Integer.parseInt(line.trim());//needed trim or it kept throwing an error. Suggested by Liam.
            // System.out.println(nextNumber);
            addLast(nextNumber); // takes the number given by parseint and puts it last
            System.out.println(nextNumber);
        }
        input.close();


    }
    private Node header;
    private Node trailer;
    private int size = 0;

    public DoublyLinkedList() {
        header = new Node(0, null, null);
        trailer = new Node(0, header, null);
        header.setNext(trailer);

    }



    public String toString() {
        String toReturn = "";

        Node current = header;


        while (current != null) {
            toReturn += current.getElement();//Credit to Liam (do not know last name, a CS student friend)
            current = current.getNext();

            if (current == null) {
                break;
            } else {
                toReturn += " -> "; // Allows for -> to be put in between the numbers 

            }

        }

        return toReturn;
    }



    public void reverseList() {
        // complete this method
    }

    public void addAfter(int newInfo, int afterThis) {
        Node tmp = new Node(newInfo,header.next, trailer.prev);
    tmp.prev = header.next;
    header.next = header;
    tmp.next = header.next;

    if(afterThis == null)
        newInfo.addLast();
    }

    public void negateList() {
        // complete this method
    }


    public void addFirst(int e) {
        Node tmp = new Node(e, header, null);
        if(header != null ) {header.prev = tmp;}
        header = tmp;
        if(trailer == null) { trailer = tmp;}
        size++;
    }

    public void addLast(int e) {

        Node tmp = new Node(e, null, trailer);
        if(trailer != null) {
            trailer.next = tmp;
            }
        trailer = tmp;
        if(header == null) {
            header = tmp;


        size++;
        }
}

    public int size() {
        return size;//line 39 size
    }

    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return size == 0;
    }

}
```

this is what I have so far. Again,I just need a little guidance on the addAfter. I appreciate any education with LinkedLists because they are proving a hard thing for me to grasp. Thanks!

Comment: here is a wikipedia entry with pseudocode. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list it has pseudocode for 'addafter'

Comment: Oh wow, of course someone else can find it! This helps a bunch
Thanks! !

Comment: @Talik am I missing an initialization for newInfo and afterThis? Only reason I ask is because my professor is usually good at giving us the variables we need so there is no confusion. I see them being passed into the addAfter method, but not intialized anywhere

Comment: Newinfo is the new number you want to add (you will make a new node of it) and after this is the value of the node you will add it after (so you first have to iterate the list to find your node with the afterthis value)

Comment: OH,  i see where we are getting those numbers. I see them in my test class. I just edited my code with.. what I think is going on the right track with addAfter. Can anyone tell me if i am heading in the right direction.

Comment: @Talik okay, if i remove both my print statements in my .. public DoublyLinkedList(String fileName) throws IOException method. I actually get nothing to print out.. is something wrong with that method or the toString method?

Comment: IOException usually gets thrown when you want to read or write something from your OS. I think the comments are a bad place to discuss it, since I would like to see a stacktrace. Did you fix it by now?

Comment: show me the line where you call the DoublyLinkedList() -> whats the parameter you pass in ? I guess it's not a valid file name

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about this logically, a double linked list is a series of nodes that looks like:

[image]

How would we go about adding something after B, but before C?

1. Take our new item, and set it to b's next and C's prev.
2. Take B and set it to our item's prev.
3. Take C and set it to our items's next.

There is also the special case, where you are adding after D or the last element in the list. In this situation you simply set D's next, and the new item's prev.

Comment: I appreciate the image! Makes things easier to visualize! This does help with understanding it!
Thank you

Comment: I will take this information and try to work this out. Thanks again.

Comment: so if i am passing in newInfo and afterThis..
will it be something like 
Node tmp = new Node(newInfo,header.next, trailer.prev); to satisfy #1?

Comment: IF and only if Header and Trailer are the ONLY elements in the list. You are close, but imagine the list has 5 elements.

Comment: Node newNode = Node(newInfo, B.Next, C.prev);

Comment: sorry I haven't closed it yet, got super busy with other stuff, but I am looking at it again now and just updated it with what I have currently. Do I need the if statement to place the new info at the end if there is nothing else after? if that makes sense

Comment: I am usually fine with public classes and variables, but I always get a bit tripped up when private is involved and you have to incorporate .next and .prev stuff